# Display information about an item based on dropdown in InfoPath

Tags: ms-access, dropdown, infopath

In InfoPath, I would like to display information about an item based on a dropdown selection.

I have a table that contains data about computer systems. I would like some of that information to be displayed in InfoPath based on what is chosen in the dropdown. The dropdown is based on the site the computer system is located and I would like to display the IP Address, the computer name, the Address of the site, the type of device it is.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Never used InfoPath so not sure. On a normal Access form, this can be accomplished several ways.

1. multi-column combobox has the related info and textboxes reference columns of combobox
2. include the related table in form RecordSource but prevent edit of the lookup table data by locking the textboxes
3. DLookup()

Any of those transferrable to InfoPath?